# Upgrading PHP 5.3.3 to 5.4.4 in CentOS 6.4

Tags: yum, centos-6, php5

I'm using CentOS 6.4 (centos-release-6-4.el6.centos.10.x86_64). I'm trying to upgrade the php version from **5.3.3** to **5.4.4** by using:

```
yum upgrade php-mysql php-devel php-gd php-pecl-memcache php-pspell php-snmp php-xmlrpc php-xml
```

and

```
yum upgrade php
```

...but this is the only message i'm getting:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.netnitco.net
 * extras: mirror.wiredtree.com
 * updates: mirror.thelinuxfix.com
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

I already ran:

```
yum update
```

and everything is in order. I also checked for exclusions of `php-*` in `/etc/yum.conf` but nothing was found. Any ideas? Thanks!

**Update: solution**

Thanks to [@mirkobrankovic](https://superuser.com/users/224210/mirkobrankovic) I ended doing this (on a 64-bit OS):

```
wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm
yum --enablerepo=remi upgrade php-mysql php-devel php-gd php-pecl-memcache php-pspell php-snmp php-xmlrpc php-xml
```

Comment: This question is closed as off-topic because it was cross posted to Server Fault: http://serverfault.com/questions/520752/upgrading-php-5-3-3-to-5-4-4-in-centos-6-4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/466394/how-to-upgrade-php-to-5-4-10-on-centos-6-3) can help you.
Use the remi repository, you can't get it from CentOS base.
How to add [remi repo](http://linuxdrops.com/how-to-add-epel-and-remi-repository-to-centos/)

Comment: Thanks! One of the answers also recommend to download and compile the required php version. I think I'll try that as well.

Answer (score 9):

To update PHP 5.3.3 to 5.4.4:

```
wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm
yum --enablerepo=remi upgrade php-mysql php-devel php-gd php-pecl-memcache php-pspell php-snmp php-xmlrpc php-xml
```

Comment: This worked for me.